# Unable to insert date in postgre using python scrapy framework

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, scrapy

I am inserting crawl data in postgreSQL. This is my code of scrapy to insert data

```
if spider.name == 'indianexpress':

            self.cur.execute("insert into feed_indianexpress(headline,link,date) values(%s,%s,%s)", (item['headline'], item['link'],datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
            self.connection.commit()
```

But I am getting following Traceback

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "16:40:30"
```

It is due to data format. Kidly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are feeding the `date` column with the wrong date format. Postgresql expects `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Change this `datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")` to this `date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`